# typing in bold font in algorithmic environment

Tags: bold, algorithmic

Is there a way to type some words in bold in an algorithmic environment? I want to have the word **stop** typed, but when I use \STOP, this gives me an error.

Comment: Would \textbf{STOP} work in your example?  It usually helps to post a full example to illustrate your problem.

Comment: yes, it actually does work now (using \textbf{stop} ). I tried that earlier, and for some reason it didn't work then.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).